# How do I use or convert an integer array of 256 and fit it into a RGB value?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I would like to use my integer array data of 256 to display using RGB values, where I fix the R and B values and use the variable as the integer array data. I thought of another method which is to assign each value with colors but it would take a long process is there any other solution to do this? I am using python, GUI and Turtle to display the color and shape.

Here is my code.

```
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
array = np.loadtxt(file_path, delimiter= ',', skiprows=390,max_rows=401)
arr1 = array[1]
arr2 = array[2]
arr3 = array[3]
arr4 = array[4]
arr5 = array[5]
arr6 = array[6]
arr7 = array[7]
arr8 = array[8]
arr9 = array[9]
arr10 = array[10]
arr11= array[11]
arr12 = array[12]
arr13 = array[13]
arr14 = array[14]
arr15 = array[15]
arr16 = array[16]
arr17 = array[17]
arr18 = array[18]
arr19 = array[19]
arr20 = array[20]
total1 = arr1 + arr2 + arr3 + arr4 + arr5 + arr6 + arr7 + arr8 + arr9 + arr10 + arr11 + arr12 + arr13 + arr14 + arr15 + arr16 + arr17 + arr18 +arr19 + arr20

Average2 = total1 / 20


    #Convert Numpy float array to integer array in 256 
IntAverage2  = np.int_(Average2)



        #Declaring i as dataset

i2=IntAverage2


X2 = np.array(range(0, 256))
Y2 = i2

tr = turtle.Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("white")
screen.colormode(255)


s = 200
tr.pencolor(41,array[i],41)

tr.width(width =3)
tr.speed(speed = 10)
for i in range(100):
    tr.forward(s)
    tr.right(90)
    s = s-2
turtle.done()
```

Ignore the i in the RGB value under the tr.pencolor. It is wrong

Comment: You can reduce the first 20 lines of your code, where you calculate the average, with  `average=numpy.average(array)`

Comment: However, at least to me, it's not clear neither what you did nor what your problem is.

Comment: I want to use my data from my array to plot my graphical display through RGB color however, since its in an integer array I could not fit it to an RGB color.